# Fabric Composer, how to find network config variables?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer, hyperledger-explorer

I have a business network running which I created using Composer. I have exposed REST APIs and all is looking good! However...

I would now like to find various config data about the network to connect Hyperledger Explorer, so I need the below:

```
{
    "network-config": {
        "org1": {
            "name": "peerOrg1",
            "mspid": "Org1MSP",
            "peer1": {
                "requests": "grpcs://127.0.0.1:7051",
                "events": "grpcs://127.0.0.1:7053",
                "server-hostname": "peer0.org1.example.com",
                "tls_cacerts": "fabric-path/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt"
            },
            "peer2": {
                "requests": "grpcs://127.0.0.1:8051",
                "events": "grpcs://127.0.0.1:8053",
                "server-hostname": "peer1.org1.example.com",
                "tls_cacerts": "fabric-path/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer1.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt"
            },
            "admin": {
                "key": "fabric-path/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore",
                "cert": "fabric-path/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts"
            }
        },
    },
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": "8080",
    "channel": "mychannel",
    "keyValueStore": "/tmp/fabric-client-kvs",
    "eventWaitTime": "30000",
}
```

Also I would like to understand how I can scale my network, i.e deploy to real nodes (not just IBM cloud).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have pasted a sample below which was working for me on a Development Fabric for Composer v0.17.  I would suggest you check the channel name, and the locations of the crypto material.  Note also that Port 8080 is also used by Composer Playground so you might see a port conflict there

```
    {
"network-config": {
    "org1": {
        "name": "peerOrg1",
        "mspid": "Org1MSP",
        "peer1": {
            "requests": "grpc://127.0.0.1:7051",
            "events": "grpc://127.0.0.1:7053",
            "server-hostname": "peer0.org1.example.com",
            "tls_cacerts": "/home/ibm/fabric-tools/fabric-scripts/hlfv11/composer/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt"
        },
        "admin": {
            "key": "/home/ibm/fabric-tools/fabric-scripts/hlfv11/composer/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore",
            "cert": "/home/ibm/fabric-tools/fabric-scripts/hlfv11/composer/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts"
        }
    }
},
"host": "localhost",
"port": "8081",
"channel": "composerchannel",
"keyValueStore": "/tmp/fabric-client-kvs",
"eventWaitTime": "30000",
"mysql": {
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": "3306",
    "database": "fabricexplorer",
    "username": "root",
    "passwd": "******"
}
}
```

This document may help you with [extending the Fabric](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-add-an-organization-to-your-hyperledger-fabric-blockchain/index.html):

Comment: Thanks, for the code and link, whilst this is the code which will work it does not really explain how one would find the details for their own network. I will add the method I found.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the way to get the the above config for each network. When creating your fabric composer network, you will have the following folder:

`~/fabric-tools`

It will contain a file called `Devserver_connection.json` in which you will find the `grpc` addresses of peers.

Also in the folder you can drill into the file system to get to:

`~/fabric-tools/fabric-scripts/hlfv1/composer/crypto-config`

And here you will find your keys needed to allow access to the explorer to your network.

Good luck!